# "Let's play" - летсплей?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Стикнувся із проблемою перекладу нового англійського вислову "let's play" (запис проходження комп'ютерної гри) - Гугл перекладач дає варіант "давайте пограємо", а на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/letsplei) можна зустріти варіант "летсплей" та його пояснення, а також варіанти "нумограй", "заграймо", "пограймо", а на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let's_Play) бачимо лише варіант "зіграймо". Отож як краще перекладати це слово - транслітерувати його чи вживати варіант із онлайн перекладачів (однак, як тоді бути з таким словом як "let's player" (людина, яка знімає та коментує летсплеї), бо в такому випадку єдиним варіантом буде "[нумогравець](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/letspleier)")?

Мені здається, що найкращий варіант "нумограймо", але такого слова немає в Академічному тлумачному словику, а тому, чи буде його вживання правильним?

Comment: Що означає «Let's play»? Що означає «Let's player»? Де Ви бачите на сайті «Словотвір» варіант «летсплей»?

Comment: У Вас усе ще не вистачає пояснення, що таке «let's play» і «let's player». Те, що Ви надали посилання на Словотвір — це добре, але пояснення задачі (еквівалент чого саме треба віднайти) має бути в самому запитанні, а не лише в прилінкованих матеріалах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Мені здається, Ви не зовсім правильно трактуєте наведені Вами джерела.</sub>

<sub>По-перше, «Словотвір» **не пропонує** варіант «летсплей»; навпаки, за своєю природою той сайт бореться з такими прямими запозиченнями (і в цьому випадку він пропонує варіанти «нумограй», «заграймо» і «пограймо»).</sub>

<sub>По-друге, Вікіпедія **не вважає** «зіграймо» українським відповідником терміну «let's play»; «зіграймо» там наведене суто в дужках в ролі дослівного перекладу — не більше (далі стаття використовує «летсплей» і «let's play»).</sub>

Допоки якийсь суто український відповідник для «lеt's play» не набув загального вжитку, мені здається, єдиним варіантом є **вжиток прямих запозичень («летсплей», «летсплеєр»)**. Спроби ввести власний термін похвальні, але навряд чи можуть бути успішними на поточному етапі (але це лише моя точка зору).

Крім того, якщо вже розглядати неологізми українського походження, то запропоновані варіанти «нумограй», «заграймо» і «пограймо» мені не дуже подобаються (навіть якщо вважати створення неологізму доречним). Другорядна причина — це те, що ці слова майже не сприймаються як іменники (особливо «заграймо» і «пограймо» — «Роман щойно виклав на свій канал три нових *погра́йми*», чи як воно має вживатися?). А першочергова причина, що, навіть якщо змусити себе сприймати ці слова як іменники, вони, на мою думку, радше підходять для того, що закликає до гри (наприклад, трейлера чи реклами), а не для відеозаписів чужого проходження (які фактично можуть використовуватися як сурогат гри). Я б запропонував радше щось на зразок «післягра́й» (адже глядач бачить відеозапис гри, що, найімовірніше, вже відбулася; якщо ж мова про стрим, то там вже є [відповідні новотвори](//slovotvir.org.ua/words/strymer), до яких за бажанням можна додати «гро-», наприклад, «гростру́м»/«гропоті́к», «грострума́р»/«гроживомо́вець») або «гра́гляд»/«гро́гляд»/«ігро́гляд» (від «гра» і «о́гляд»; той, хто його переглядає — «гроглядач», а той, хто його знімає — «(гро)глядоро́б») чи «(і)гропрохі́д» — якби вважав такі спроби доречними.